# How to draw lines between two buttons in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have 9 buttons which are arranged in 3*3 matrix in vb.net.

```
btn1    btn2     btn3
btn4    btn5     btn6
btn7    btn8     btn9
```

Suppose, if I click on btn1 then move my mouse to btn2 then btn3 and at last click on btn6 then line should be drawn from btn1 to btn2 to btn3 to btn6.

Like this:

```
btn1----btn2----btn3
                 |
btn4    btn5    btn6

btn7    btn8    btn9
```

Suppose, if i first click on btn6 then move my mouse to btn9 to btn8 to btn5 and last click on btn2 then line should be drawn this way:

```
btn1    btn2    btn3

btn4    btn5    btn6
         |        |
btn7    btn8----btn9
```

How to draw this kind of lines? 
Any ideas?

Comment: Custom controls, handling paint events, store the information in variables, etc.

Comment: Are you restricting it to only horizontal and vertical lines? For example could you go from btn1 to btn5 in a single move?

Comment: Yes. we can go diagonally too like btn1 to btn5 to btn7 as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this in a Paint event; either on the form or add a picturebox and add the event to it.
Is the aim to provide a numeric "keypad" that the operator drags the mouse around? If this is the case then I would add the picture box and draw the "buttons" inside the paint event of the picture box. That way you store the location of the "buttons" and in code can capture the mouseDown and mouseMove events to work out which buttons the mouse has been clicked on and moved over. to draw the lines use the e.graphics.DrawLine(pens.black,x1,y1,x2,y2) function.
If you do it on the form then you will need to know the location of the buttons and draw between them, these could be obtained by the program at runtime.

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e as PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
   Dim X1 as Integer = Button1.Location.X + Button1.Width /2
   Dim Y1 as Integer = Button1.Location.Y + Button1.Height/2
   Dim X2 as Integer = Button2.Location.X + Button2.Width /2
   Dim Y2 as Integer = Button2.location.Y + Button2.Height/2
   Dim X3 as Integer = Button3.Location.X + Button3.Width /2
   Dim Y3 as Integer = Button3.location.Y + Button3.Height/2
   Dim X4 as Integer = Button4.Location.X + Button4.Width /2
   Dim Y4 as Integer = Button4.location.Y + Button4.Height/2
   Dim X5 as Integer = Button5.Location.X + Button5.Width /2
   Dim Y5 as Integer = Button5.location.Y + Button5.Height/2
   Dim X6 as Integer = Button6.Location.X + Button6.Width /2
   Dim Y6 as Integer = Button6.location.Y + Button6.Height/2
   Dim X7 as Integer = Button7.Location.X + Button7.Width /2
   Dim Y7 as Integer = Button7.location.Y + Button7.Height/2
   Dim X8 as Integer = Button8.Location.X + Button8.Width /2
   Dim Y8 as Integer = Button8.location.Y + Button8.Height/2
   Dim X9 as Integer = Button9.Location.X + Button9.Width /2
   Dim Y9 as Integer = Button9.location.Y + Button9.Height/2
   e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, X1, Y1, X2, Y2)
   e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, X2, Y2, X3, Y3)
   e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, X3, Y3, X6, Y6)
End Sub
```